# Uniquely idenitfy the extension change from excel to word in asp.net C# file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net

**I created one excel file and change the extension type=”.docx”.I try to upload.it is uploading but if content and extension type both are different. then i need to block that one i tried few codes to avoid this with magic number and mime type but magic number is same for word and excel and zip also if i change the extension then mime type also changed. So i need to identify this content with any unique identifier
   **Here I have my sample code for finding the mime type and Magic number****

```
   string FileExtension = FileName.Substring((FileName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)).ToUpper();
string MagicNumber = HexaDecimalData.Substring(0, 47);  
string HexaDecimalData=string.Empty;
string MimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(_File.FileName);
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(FileName))
{
BinaryReader Reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
Reader.BaseStream.Position = 0x0; // The offset you are reading the data from  
byte[] data = Reader.ReadBytes(0x10); // Read 16 bytes into an array  
HexaDecimalData = BitConverter.ToString(data);
Reader.Close();
} switch (FileExtension)
{

                                case "XLS":
                                    if ((!MimeType.Equals("application/excel", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && 
                                        !MimeType.Equals("application/vnd.ms-excel", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && 
                                        !MimeType.Equals("application/x-excel", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && 
                                        !MimeType.Equals("application/x-msexcel", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) || 
                                        (!MagicNumber.StartsWith("D0-CF-11-E0-A1-B1-1A-E1") ))
                                        ErrorMessage = "Invalid File";
                                    break;
                                case "XLSX":
                                    if ((!MimeType.Equals("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) || 
                                        (!MagicNumber.StartsWith("50-4B-03-04")  && !MagicNumber.StartsWith("50-4B-05-06")  && !MagicNumber.StartsWith("50-4B-07-08") ))
                                        ErrorMessage = "Invalid File";
                                    break;
                                case "PDF":
                                    if ((!MimeType.Equals("application/pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) || (!MagicNumber.StartsWith("25-50-44-46") ))
                                        ErrorMessage = "Invalid File";
                                    break;
                                case "DOCX":
                                    if ((!MimeType.Equals("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) || 
                                        (!MagicNumber.StartsWith("50-4B-03-04")  && !MagicNumber.StartsWith("50-4B-05-06")  && !MagicNumber.StartsWith("50-4B-07-08") ))
                                        ErrorMessage = "Invalid File";
                                    break;
                                case "DOC":
                                    if ((!MimeType.Equals("application/msword", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) || (!MagicNumber.StartsWith("D0-CF-11-E0-A1-B1-1A-E1") ))
                                        ErrorMessage = "Invalid File";
                                    break;


                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14276391/911804

from above link:

> However, note that all Office 2007 file formats ending in "x" are zip
>   compressed XML documents. So this approach is not 100% safe but at
>   least it might help you to filter out some invalid.

**Updated:**
If you want solid solution then try the following, but it will be time consuming.

In you switch case statement, try to open the uploaded file using Office DLL's, if opened properly then it's the correct format.
Add assembly reference and use Ms-Word assembly DLL's function.

It may be time consuming, but this will give 100% solution.

Comment: I tested ur comments for excel and word both are return same ScanFileForMimeType "application/x-zip-compressed".So I am not able to find the correct one.

Comment: @Subramaniyan.V read my updated answer, It's like 'Renan' answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your hands dirty for a proper format validation. You have to try opening the file with the [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425).

Do a `try-catch`. If the try block ends successfuly, then it's a Word document - the catch block will tell you that either it is not a Word document, or something about it is broken.

For example:

```
try
{
    // "path" is a string with the path to the file.
    // The "false" parameter indicates we don't intend do edit the file.
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, false))
    {
        // Seems like we got an ok file.
    }
}
catch
{
    // Let your user know that they should upload a proper Word file.
}
```

But do try a MIME validation prior to that, it'll save you the overhead of trying to open something you already know not to be a valid document.

Comment: I can able to upload any formatted files(Word,excel,PDF).but I want restrict with only one condition that content and extension should be same.So I am not able to use WordprocessingDocument.Open

Comment: I tried with in the read block (using{})also it is not working.

Comment: Ok, two things: 1) I don't see how you are unable to open a document to validate its format - you will never know that the content is right unless you explicitly open it and 2) if you say something is not working in Stack Overflow, you have to provide details like any error messages you are getting, expected behavior vs what you got, etc.